# How to load JSON data based on selected value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to this and I dont know what I am doing wrong.

In my json file I have several lines but I only need to log the requested

```
<a href="#" id="get-data" data-id="100" data-foo="100">Get JSON data</a>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


  <script>

      $('#get-data').click(function () {

          var myDiv = document.querySelector('#get-data');

          var mySetValue = myDiv.dataset.foo


          console.log (mySetValue)
          var showData = $('#show-data');
          var url = 'example.json';
          var data = {
              value: mySetValue
          };
          $.getJSON(url, data) 
            console.log(data);
      });


  </script>
```

and this is my json file

```
[
{
  "key": "First",
  "value": 100
},{
  "key": "Second",
  "value": false
},{
  "key": "Last",
  "value": "Mixed"
},
  {
  "key": "First",
  "value": 100
},{
  "key": "Last",
  "value": "Mixed"
},
  {
  "key": "First",
  "value": 100
},{
  "key": "Second",
  "value": false
},{
  "key": "Last",
  "value": "Mixed"
}]
```

I need to load only the data associated with the data-foo of my button but instead, i only get one value in return.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Missing handler as a callback? asynchronous problem?

Comment: Did you know that `$.getJSON(url, data)` makes an asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using Jquery as an API, within Jquery there is a function for ajax that you can be using that helps to bring information from an ajax file/response.

Read more about in [W3S Jquery Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Your code will result in something like this.

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/file.json',          
    success: function(data){ 

        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

[image]

**Possible problems that can happen**

1. If you are not running this on a PHP server or have "[Crossdomain](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)" permission, HTML / PHP will not give you permission to open the "external file"
2. Ajax is an asynchronous function, this means that if you assign an X value inside, it will only assign the value when the external structure finishes its execution ... In short, it executes what is outside of ajax first and then what is inside, it is possible to solve this with [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [await/async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

To do an await with a promise you will have to have a "main" function that is an asynchronous function, otherwise this function will not accept the await condition.

**Resolving the asynchronous problem**.

```
async function main(){

    var result = await getAssycFunction();

    console.log(result);

}

function getAssycFunction(){

    return new Promise((result, reject) =>{

        result("Result");

    });

}
```

As you asked me in the comments, to separate the values there is no "magic function", but what can be done is a loop that goes through all the houses and separates in a second array only the ones you want.

```
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {

    if (data[i]['value'] == 100) {

        values.push(data[i]);
    }

}

result(values);
```

a small note: do not want to hide information from the end user when separating the variables, once you have an Ajax request, the user has access to the ajax file to be able to read.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can get the entire file with either json or ajax but I only want to extract the data with value:100 from the file. Not all.

Comment: When Jquery returns a `data` it resumes an object, it is possible to select items from that object, in case it is returning an array, wait a minute I'm editing this for a more complete answer that can help you.

Comment: sorry for getting a little big, but I think that should answer your questions.

Comment: isnt there another way to approach this?

Comment: I mean, i am trying to select certain data from the json file. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: If the value is static, you can pull it straight from the array box ... something like: `var x = data[i]`, where `i` is the value of the array you want to collect, if you want the third value ... you type 2, because the matrix always starts at 0

Comment: For more questions on how to extract information from an object ... you can read this article about [objects in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Comment: Hello, I'm passing by again to see if it worked, if it worked, you can close this question by evaluating this answer as a correct answer.